# GNUPLOT: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points Can't plot with an empty x range

Tags: gnuplot

I'm new to this. Currently, I am trying to plot my memory consumption for my server.
I'm using Gnuplot and getting stuck at

**warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
         Can't plot with an empty x range!**

```
set title "Memory Growth" font ",20" textcolor lt 2
set xdata time
set timefmt "%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S"
set format x "%m-%d-%y\t%H:%M:%S"
set xrange ["12/18/19":"12/24/19"]
set format y '%.0s%cB'
set xlabel "Time"
set xtics rotate by -270 
set xtics out offset 0,-1.0
set ylabel "Memory (GB)"
set datafile separator "\,"
plot    'TRDFDSERVER19_System Monitor Log.csv' using 1:2 title '19\ProcessPrivate,Bytes' with line,\
        'TRDFDSERVER19_System Monitor Log.csv' using 1:3 title '19\ProcessVirtual Bytes' with line,\
        'TRDFDSERVER19_System Monitor Log.csv' using 1:4 title '19\ProcessPrivate Bytes' with line,\
        'TRDFDSERVER19_System Monitor Log.csv' using 1:5 title '19\ProcessVirtual Bytes' with line
```

Example input

```
12/18/2019 06:29:30.029,1699074048,2442911744,102342656,831528960
12/18/2019 06:29:31.030,1699074048,2442911744,102342656,831528960
12/18/2019 06:29:32.029,1699074048,2442911744,102342656,831528960
12/18/2019 06:29:33.029,1699074048,2442911744,102342656,831528960
12/18/2019 06:29:34.029,1699074048,2442911744,102342656,831528960
12/18/2019 06:29:35.029,1699074048,2442911744,102342656,831528960
12/18/2019 06:29:36.029,1699074048,2442911744,102342656,831528960
12/18/2019 06:29:37.029,1699074048,2442911744,102342656,831528960
12/18/2019 06:29:38.029,1699074048,2442911744,102342656,831528960
12/18/2019 06:29:39.029,1699074048,2442911744,102342656,831528960
12/18/2019 06:29:40.029,1699074048,2442911744,102342656,831528960
12/18/2019 06:29:41.029,1699074048,2442911744,102342656,831528960
12/18/2019 06:29:42.029,1699074048,2442911744,102342656,831528960
```

**Edit**                                                                                                                         **^
         all points y value undefined!**

After the problem above is fixed. Now, i got "Y value" undefine. Any suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have a wrong time format, according to your data it should  be

```
set timefmt "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S"
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, Now, one more question. I got stuck at                                                                                                                         ^
         all points y value undefined!  Please advise how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

if you have the format `"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"` then you should set the range accordingly:

Instead of

```
set xrange ["12/18/19":"12/24/19"]
```

you should set

```
set xrange ["12/18/2019":"12/24/2019"]
```